# Expected an expression error

Tags: c++, syntax, expression

I'm trying to get this code working but ran into this error, in which I have no idea how to fix. I've tried searching Google but nothing that came up helped.

```
Ghost::Ghost()
{
    ghost = SDL_LoadBMP("media/ghost.bmp");
    lightning = SDL_LoadBMP("media/light.bmp");
    monsterDead = false;
    deathCounted = false;

    posX = 4450;
    posY = 490;

    xVel = 200;
    yVel = 300;

    monsterPos = {posX, posY, 122, 130};
// Error Here    ^

}
```

This is just the part of the code... the error at the place highlighted.

Comment: I'm on the edge of my seat!  What's the error?

Comment: May be the Ghost is lightning it!

Comment: What is the error and what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, yes, the elusive **missing closing bracket error**. This is known to trouble programmers all over the world, and studies have show that it can be solved by adding a closing bracket at the end:

```
Ghost::Ghost()
{
    ghost = SDL_LoadBMP("media/ghost.bmp");lightning = SDL_LoadBMP("media/light.bmp");monsterDead = false;deathCounted = false;

    posX = 4450;posY = 490;

    xVel = 200;yVel = 300;

    monsterPos = {posX, posY, 122, 130};//

} //<--- HERE!!!
```

**Per your edit:**

```
monsterPos = {posX, posY, 122, 130};
```

appears to not be supported by your compiler, as it's not an intialization, but an assignment. You'll have to assign the members of `monsterPos` one by one.

Comment: Thnk you, but I just forgot to copy everything.. the code carries on after that and I did have a closing bracket.

Comment: That's a bogus answer. The closing brace has always been in the code; the code was just poorly formatted.

Comment: @KerrekSB it was not, see the 1st version. Actually, any version prior to `}` being added by an editor (not the op).

Comment: @Kerrek SB, no it wasn't, OP just added it